# Rails 5 Postgres - replace all resource with one tag with multiple tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

I recently migrated over a bunch of models to one umbrella model, and the issue is that the tag_list for all the old models migrated over as a long string, rather than delimited tags.

For example:

```
Post.tag_list = "popcorn, salty, butter"
```

came over to the new model as:

```
"popcorn salty butter"
```

I have this SQL migration in rails

```
execute("UPDATE tags SET name='popcorn, salty, butter' WHERE LOWER(name) LIKE 'movie popcorn' ESCAPE '!';")
```

This works, but my rails app is replacing all resources with the tag `movie popcorn` with one LONG string -> `"popcorn, salty, butter"`, when i just want `popcorn, salty, butter` - **note the double quotations** (I don't want the double quotation mark string, as my app uses commas as the delimiter to indicate multiple tags)

I want to replace all resources that have the tag(s) `movie popcorn` with three tags instead: `popcorn`, `salty` and `butter` - How can i do that with the above code? Since it's working similarly, but adding in double quotation marks, which does not allow the app to function for tag searching.

I am using acts as taggable and rails 5.1.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of renaming tag, it’s necessary to create tags `popcorn`, `salty` and `butter`, each as a single record of `tags` table, and then update your resources. Single-runner for this can look like:

```
tags = %w[popcorn salty butter].map do |tag|
  Tag.find_or_create_by(name: tag)
end
Post.joins(:tags).where("tags.name = 'movie popcorn'").each do |post|
  post.tags = tags
end
```

Migrations won't help there.

**UPDATE:** In case of using `acts_as_taggable_on` gem the code will look like:

```
Post.tagged_with('movie popcorn').each do |post|
  post.tag_list = "popcorn, salty, butter"
  post.save
end
```

Comment: Thank you! Would this have to be run in the console or in a migration file?

Comment: Migrations are for database structure changes. This code can be run in console.

Comment: I don't have a tag model as I use acts as taggable on.. ```[1] pry(main)> tags = %w[popcorn salty butter].map do |tag|
[1] pry(main)*   Tag.find_or_create_by(name: tag)
[1] pry(main)* end  
NameError: uninitialized constant Tag
from (pry):2:in `block in __pry__'```

Comment: Sorry, I’m not familiar with that gem. Can your share a link to it’s repo?

Comment: It's a fairly popular tagging gem that is used in the rails community. https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on - Thanks for your help i really appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer. Basically, that gem's documentation contains everything to manage tags.